# OLEDB Connection was unhandled error

Tags: database, vb.net, windows, oledb, ole

I am trying to link some database records into textboxes and a listbox with visual basic and OLEDB but when I debug the program, even though the database is in the `bin/debug` folder, the program isn't recognising it.

Below is the code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source = Hospital.mdb"
        Dim dtPatientsIDs As New DataTable
        Dim daPatientIDs As New OleDbDataAdapter _
        ("Select [Patient ID] From Patients", ConnectString)

        daPatientIDs.Fill(dtPatientsIDs)
        lstPatientIDs.DataSource = dtPatientsIDs
        lstPatientIDs.DisplayMember = "Patient ID"

        OleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(DsPatientsAndWards1)
        txtWardName.DataBindings.Add("Text", DsPatientsAndWards1, _
                                 "Patients.Ward Name")
        txtWardType.DataBindings.Add("Text", DsPatientsAndWards1, _
                                 "Patients.Ward Type")



    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
        BindingContext(DsPatientsAndWards1, "Patients").Position = _
        BindingContext(DsPatientsAndWards1, "Patients").Position - 1

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        BindingContext(DsPatientsAndWards1, "Patients").Position = _
        BindingContext(DsPatientsAndWards1, "Patients").Position + 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnFind_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFind.Click
        Dim index As Short
        index = lstPatientIDs.SelectedIndex
        BindingContext(DsPatientsAndWards1, "Patients").Position = index

    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: here is a picture of what the form looks like]

[here is the error and its location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp3aU.png)

Comment: There is no Connection object created...that is probably part of the exception message.  The DB might be better saved to a Users folder...there wont be VS BIN folders when deployed

Comment: We cant help you unless you tell us what the error is and where it is.

Comment: This exception has also an InnerException property with a more meaningful message. Please add it

Comment: error is now at the bottom of the question

Comment: i changed the provider to 12.0 and the source to .accdb and the hopsital database is still in the bin/debug folder

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
Dim daPatientIDs As New OleDbDataAdapter _
    ("Select [Patient ID] From Patients", ConnectString)
```

to

```
Dim Con as NEW OleDBConnection(ConnectionString)
Dim daPatientIDs As New OleDbDataAdapter _
    ("Select [Patient ID] From Patients", Con)
```

and add

```
Con.open()
```

before

```
    OleDbDataAdapter1.Fill(DsPatientsAndWards1)
```

Comment: I am still receiving the exact same error of the data source not being a valid path

Comment: Does the Hospital.mdb exist in your bin/debug/ folder for your program